# Geoserver: Automate SLD validation

Tags: geoserver

Two questions:

1. Is Geoserver SLD validation the same as validation with some XML Validator?
2. Is there a way of automating SLD Validation? Let´s say I´d have to validate 700 SLDs – doing this programmatically (by terminal or REST) would be more than helpful.

Comment: Yes and no that I know of

Comment: Please only ask one question per question - as per the [Tour].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's pure xml validation against the SLD XML schemas. However, it's against the extended SLD schema that GeoServer has internally, e.g.:

http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/schemas/sld/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd

So you can take this schema and use a command line validator against the GeoServer data directory I believe

Comment: great! just checked with xmllint which worked against the schema, thanks!